# Getting an Error when trying to connect Visual Studio application to Oracle

Tags: visual-studio-2010, oracle, tnsnames

I am new to Oracle.I amy trying to connect my Visual Studio 2010 VB application with an Oracle Server on a remote server.

I configured my tnsnames.ora by proving the host name and service name. When I tried to test the connection using the Add Connection functionality in Server Exploreer I got the following error:

ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

Does this mean the values I entered into tnsnames.ora are wrong. Or do I need to configure anyother documents- listener.ora for example? I  have not made any other changes except what I have mentioned above. Please let me know how to resolve this issue as it is time sensitive.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take Visual Studio out of the picture first.  You need to confirm your Oracle client is configured properly on your machine.

If you installed the Oracle connection tools, you should have `tnsping` installed.  From the command line, enter

```
tnsping <server_name>
```

This will try to find the Oracle server using the configuration specified in your tnsnames file (if your sqlnet file is configured to have Oracle use the tnsnames protocol).  If it finds it, it will tell you what method it used.  You can then use this information for your Visual Studio connection.

Make sure your sqlnet file is correct.  You use this file to tell Oracle the order of protocols to use to resolve servers (e.g. tnsnames, ldap, etc.).  Mine looks as follows:

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NTS)
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH = (LDAP,TNSNAMES)
NAMES.DEFAULT_DOMAIN = <domain_name>
```

Comment: Thanks.I tried tnsping and got the following:                                                          Used HOSTNAME adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=))(ADDRESS=(PROTO
COL=TCP)(HOST=165.91.176.54)(PORT=1521)))
OK (0 msec)                                                                Does this mean it has een configured properly? Do I have to connect using hostname? I have just been testing the connection using my username and password in the Add Connection function of Visual Studio.

Comment: Also, here is my sqlnet file SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)
#NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
Should I uncomment the second line?

Comment: If tnsping returned,  that means your configuration is correct.  Do you have the Oracle Visual Studio tools installed (ODT)?  Or are you just using Server Explorer out of the box?

Comment: Also you should change your SQLNET.AuthneticationServices to the following SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NONE) if you start getting password / can't connect issues (not the 12514 error).

Comment: I don not know if Oracle Visual Studio tools are installed as I was not involved in the installation process. However I believe the issue might have something to do with the fact that I have 2 versions of the Oracle client installed as tsells had suggested. Shall I go ahead and uninstall one- because I installed it by mistake.

Comment: When you do this, check your PATH environment variable to make sure the bin directory of the Oracle client you want is still in there.

Comment: Also, you cannot connect to an Oracle server without ODT installed.  The server explorer in Visual Studio is wired up to only support SQL Server by default.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/overview/index.html

Answer (score 0):

This usually means one of two things.

1. You don't have ODP.Net installed or it is missing some dll's (unlikely)
2. You have more than one version of the oracle client on the machine and .net can't find the correct one.

Go to the system path for the machine and make sure that the FIRST oracle path in the path statement is pointing to the correct oracle client installation.

To remove oracle

1. Stop DTC service and oracle mts service if running
2. Delete All oracle directories (C:\Program Files, C:\Oracle, C:\App, etc)
3. Remove Oracle from the path statement (all entries)
4. Remove any environment variables
5. Remove Oracle entries in the Local Machine registry and Current User section (if exists)
6. Reboot the machine
7. Reinstall the correct version

Comment: You are right- I have 2 versions of the Oracle client. When I try adding connection in Visual Studio the data source drop down contains the aliases included in the tnsnames.ora of the client_2 directory. The first Oracle path in the path statement is also client_2. SO i think its is pointing to the correct client installation. What I can I do in this situation?

Comment: Honestly I would remove both Oracle installations and reinstall clean.  I have been dealing with these kinds of problems for about 5 years (oracle and .net) and it's not pretty.  It's best to run one version. I am editing my answer with the steps to cleanly remove oracle.

Comment: Would it be possible to avoid all of this and connect to the oracle databse using ODBC?